# How to secure a RESTFUL php webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am developing an apple app which talks to a restful PHP web service.

Ideally i want this web service password protected.

What is the best way of achieving this,

Is it better to use a technique similar to OAUTH or is it over kill?

Or is it better to send user password and username in server each command and check its legit before caring out each individual command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the client. If the client is 3rd party, then it needs an OAuth like solution with access tokens. If the developer of the service and the client is the same, then the basic auth approach is enough. Ofc. you have to use encrypted connection.

Comment: i think oath isn't the correct example but first and only that popped into my head. The web service and iPad is own system no other parties

Comment: Then send the username and password with every request using HTTPS. I don't think you can do much more.